# Logo image formats allowed

Tags: sharepoint-online, image

I have added a vector (.ai) image of our logo into the site assets library.  When I go to upload it as the logo, the .ai files do not show up as an option to select.  Are vector images not allowed as a logo image?  If not, does anyone know a work around?

Comment: Can't you save the image in PNG format?

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Illustrator files are accepted by Adobe programs but is not a file-format that Web Browsers accept or understand

So for you logo you're stuck with JPG , PNG , GIF